# Understanding $ \frac {e^x}{x^2} $ as $ x \to -\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

Given the limit of this function

$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^2 + e^x + 1}{x^2 + x \sin x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
     \frac {\infty}{\infty} 
\end{bmatrix} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac {e^x (1 + \frac{x^2}{e^x} + \frac{1}{e^x})} {x^2(1 + \frac{1}{x} \sin x)}
$$

Since $ \lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x = 0$ and $ \lim_{x\to -\infty} x^2 = +\infty$   ,  I'd give the result $ \frac{0}{+\infty} = 0$ but it is not correct.

What am I mistaking? Have I made any wrong assumption?

Comment: Oh, but it is **not** wrong: the limit indeed is zero. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Your assertion is correct (the limit _is_ $0$). To see that just look at the taylor series of the numerator and denominator to find that $e^x$ is the only dominant term.

Comment: @Timbuc The final result should be 1.

Comment: the right answer is $1$

Comment: The result of the **original** expression is one, but **not** of $\; \frac{e^x}{x^2}\;$ !

Comment: OP's answer is wrong when claims $e^{x}\to 0$ implies numerator goes to $0$ ($x^2/e^x\to+\infty$ as $x\to -\infty$).

Comment: As $x\to-\infty$, the square $x^2$ dominates, not the exponent. Both numerator and denominator are essentially $x^2$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic of limits:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x\cdot\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac1{x^2}=0\cdot 0= 0$$

And about the original limit:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^2 + e^x + 1}{x^2 + x \sin x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1+\frac{e^x}{x^2}+\frac1{x^2}}{1+\frac{\sin x}x}=\frac{1+0+0}{1+0}=1$$

Observe that in the limit, $\;x^2\;$ rules, **not** $\;e^x\;$ .

Comment: Since an exponential grows faster than a power when $ x \to \infty $ I took $ e^x $ instead of $ x^2 $. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x^2 + e^x + 1}{x^2 + x \sin x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
     \frac {\infty}{\infty} 
\end{bmatrix} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac {x^2 (1 + \frac{e^x}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2})} {x^2(1 + \frac{1}{x} \sin x)}=1?
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Divide top and bottom by $x^2$. Note that $e^x$ dies as $x\to -\infty$.